# python DB API - list conversion with fetchmany

Tags: python

I am trying to fetch data from one Database server and load into another. I have two cursors open and in one cursor I am fetching the data and prepping the results to run "executemany" INSERT statements on the second cursor

I am not able to use the  results as it is to run "executemany"; I tried converting to lists, copying to lists etc, but nothing seem to be working. But when I manually copy the results to clipboard and paste back again as a list - my INSERT works. Not sure what am I missing here.

```
   >>> scur.execute("select top 3 * from db1.dbo.job")
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x7f9c2a1b2930>

>>> rows = scur.fetchall()

>>> rows
[(1127, u'', u'8196660', u'', u'', 0, u'', u'', None, 35, None, 0, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, u'', 0, None, None), (1128, u'', u'8196638', u'', u'', 0, u'', u'', None, 23, None, 0, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, u'', 0, None, None), (1129, u'', u'8195737', u'', u'', 0, u'', u'', None, 22, None, 0, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, u'', 0, None, None)]
>>> icur.executemany(stmt1, rows)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 286, in executemany
    self.execute(operation, parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 187, in execute
    configuration=configuration)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 205, in execute_async
    self._execute_async(op)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 220, in _execute_async
    operation_fn()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 198, in op
    parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/impala/interface.py", line 254, in _bind_parameters
    raise ProgrammingError("Query parameters argument should be a "
impala.error.ProgrammingError: Query parameters argument should be a list, tuple, or dict object


# I am copying the above "rows" to clip board and pasting back

>>> rows_copy = [(1127, u'', u'8196660', u'', u'', 0, u'', u'', None, 35, None, 0, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, u'', 0, None, None), (1128, u'', u'8196638', u'', u'', 0, u'', u'', None, 23, None, 0, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, u'', 0, None, None), (1129, u'', u'8195737', u'', u'', 0, u'', u'', None, 22, None, 0, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, u'', 0, None, None)]
    >>> icur.executemany(stmt1, rows_copy)
# Rows are inserted into the database
    >>>
    >>> if rows == rows_copy:
...     print "same"
... else:
...     print "not same"
...
not same
>>>
>>> type(rows)
<type 'list'>
>>> type(rows_copy)
<type 'list'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below does the trick

rowlist = [list(l) for l in rows]